# grep or find and sed to replace string

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I've been at this for hours and for some reason, I cannot find out why this command will not replace the desired string. I'm trying this

```
grep -r -l 'first\.second\.third\.fourth' . | xargs -i -e sed's/first\.second\.third\.fourth/foo\.bar\.fooey/g'
```

so what I'm trying to do is recursively search through a folder with lots of files and change `"first.second.third.fourth"` to `"foo.bar.fooey"`. After I run the grep and sed command, I grep again to make sure that "first.second.third.fourth" isn't found but it comes up, what I believe is just as many times. So I'm pretty much at my wit's end.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-i` should be an argument to sed, not to xargs. And as @potong points out, the "." characters in sed's match string must be escaped, or they'll match anything.

```
grep -r -l 'first.second.third.fourth' . | xargs sed -i 's/first\.second\.third\.fourth/foo.bar.fooey/g'
```

Comment: Don't forget `.` in the LHS of the substitute command in sed means match any single character. To match a period use `\.`

Comment: @potong you're absolutely correct. I did have that in my terminal but when I copied it over, that didn't make the transfer... my fault.

Comment: Thanks @Beta for pointing me in the right direction. After some playing with it, this is what did the trick. **grep -l -r 'first\.second\.third\.fourth' ./| xargs sed  -i "" 's/first\.second\.third\.fourth/foo\.bar\.fooey/g'** Notice the Empty quotes after the -i. That was key, if you don't put in the quotes you will get an error. From my understanding the empty quotes is to erase the original file.

Comment: Why would you need to 'erase the original file'? It should work with the command provided by Beta.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a single `find`/`sed`?

```
find /YOUR/DIR -type f -iname "*YOURFILENAMEPATTERN*" \
     -exec sed -i 's/"first.second.third.fourth"/"foo.bar.fooey"/g'
```

Comment: I think he's trying to change all instances of a string, not just the ones in files whose names match a pattern. (I presume he's using grep instead of no filter at all in order to avoid altering timestamps of unaffected files.)

Comment: For every file you should only leave out the `-iname "*YOURFILENAME*"` pattern.